# Is there anything inside a package that determines if vignettes are built?

Tags: r, installation, package, devtools, vignette

I'm writing my first R package and working on vignettes, which don't always build on installation. I'm not clear whether there is anything inside the package that determines whether the vignette is built, or if this is entirely driven by build options during installation. Is there anything I could/should add to my vignette so that it builds by default? It seems this occurs with `install.packages()` for CRAN packages, but requires a bit of attention when installing from source.

Here's some example behavior for a package that has made it through the CRAN filter:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("https://github.com/AnneChao/iNEXT", build_vignettes = T, force = T)
library(iNEXT)
vignette(package = "iNEXT") #as expected, vignette appears
install_github("https://github.com/AnneChao/iNEXT", force = T)
library(iNEXT)
vignette(package = "iNEXT") # not totally expected, vignette not built with package
install.packages("iNEXT")
library(iNEXT)
vignette(package = "iNEXT") # apparently this way, by default, vignette built
```

Comment: Answer and comments below look informative: stackoverflow.com/a/19373103/8400969